# dom4j remove whitespace on XPath selects

Tags: dom4j

Is there a way in dom4j to have it trim whitespapce for the ends of strings returned by an XPath select?

The purpose is so:

David

Is not "\r\nDavid\r\n" but instead is "David"

Comment: Can you just trim the returned string results yourself?

Comment: @vtd-xml-author We feed the XPath results back to a report designer so that requires the designer adds a trim() call around the select. Works better if they can set a global setting.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use normalize-space() on your xpath 2.0 expression, for example like /html/body/table/tr/td/text()/normalize-space(.)

Comment: Unfortunately dom4j is not XPath 2.0.